# How do I configure Sublime Text 3 to use classes from Apache Commons IO?

Tags: java, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I've downloaded "commons-io-2.5-bin.tar.gz", "commons-io-2.5-bin.zip", "commons-io-2.5-src.tar.gz" and "commons-io-2.5-src.zip" from the Apache Commons website.

How do I configure sublime text so it can import classes from whichever of these files is relevant?

I also want to be able to find and import classes from Apache Commons IO automatically using the JavaImports package.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your correctly you are using Sublime for developing Java application. You shouldn't do it. Sublime Text is a text editor, for Java you need an IDE

> ...integrated development environment (IDE) is a software application that provides comprehensive facilities to computer programmers for software development

The most popular are [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/), [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) and [Intellij IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Comment: Oh ok. Downloading Intellij IDEA as I speak. Thanks!